# Velocity: Iteration issue

Tags: java, velocity

After, upgrading to velocity engine `1.7` from `1.5` an issue occurs which was not with 1.5. To explain the issue I would have to show a code snippet:

```
#foreach($someVariable in $someCollection)
 #foreach($anotherVariable in $someVariable.$anotherCollection)
   $anotherVariable.someAttribute ## This expression print in the browser as is
   ## but if I do this way
   $anotherVariable.get("someAttribute") ## works fine!
 #end
#end
```

This is happening after the upgrade (which is in `1.7`) and if I rollback the upgrade (move back to `1.5`) then I don't have to it in other way which I mention in above code snippet.

Comment: What is the type of `$anotherVariable`?

Comment: @EvanHaas it is generic ArrayList

Comment: ArrayList?? what is someAttribute then?

Comment: @NathanBubna ArrayList holding custom class as items

Comment: [java.util.ArrayList's get method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) takes only the integer index.  Is this your own custom extension of `ArrayList`?

Comment: it is a generic arraylist or list ArrayList<CustomClass> c  = ...

Comment: Velocity is just a wrapper for Java, and since there's no `ArrayList.get(String)` method, this shouldn't work in any Velocity version. It's not strange that it doesn't work anymore, it's weird that it used to work in 1.5. Anyway, what did it print with 1.5? What would `get(String)` return? A possible answer is that you had a custom uberspector that somehow converted this call into `contains` or `indexOf`. Another possible answer is that `$anotherVariable` isn't a list, you should print `$anotherVariable.class` to check the actual type.

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu just a correction here ... $someVariable is a ArrayList and $anotherVariable is a custom class which extend from a generic HashMap

Comment: What is the signature of the custom class?  And does the custom class override HashMap's get()?

Comment: @NathanBubna yes it does override.

Comment: Signature of the overriding method?  And the class?

Comment: @NathanBubna public class MyClass extends HashMap<String, Object>  implements IBaseSerialzedInterface, Comparable<MyModel>  { public Object put(String key, Object obj) { .. } public Object get(String key) { .. }  /* many other functions */}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your MyClass extends HashMap:

public Object get(Object key) {
  return get((String)key);
}

I fear Velocity may be recognizing that it is a Map and trying a shortcut that doesn't acknowledge the generics and thus is calling the wrong get() method.  But i'm not set up to confirm this on this machine, nor do i have time to do so.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your .java files.

```
#foreach($someVariable in $someCollection)
    #foreach($anotherVariable in $someVariable.$anotherCollection)
        $anotherVariable.someAttribute 
        $anotherVariable.get("someAttribute") 
    #end
#end
```

Say someVariable is an object of class X.
For your someVariable, there should be a public get() method to obtain anotherCollection in class X;
Similarly, say anotherVariable is an object of class Y.
For your anotherVariable, there should be a public get() method to obtain someAttribute in class Y.

This is applicable to both the ways in which we are trying to access someAttribute as shown above.